# How do I join table and field names in a pandas function?

Tags: python, function, pandas, concatenation

I'm creating a function that will take a table name and 2 field names and use them to do some sorting and ranking.  The problem with making this generic is that some parts of my code use syntax such as dataframename['fieldname'] whilst others just use ['fieldname'].  In the function I pass in the table name and field name separately however I then need to concatenate them in the code - this seems to cause the code to break though.

This is probably easiest to illustrate with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#Some dummy data for testing
d = {'City': ['London', 'New York', 'New York', 'London', 'Paris',
                        'Paris', 'New York', 'New York', 'London', 'Paris'],
     'Weight': [225, 454, 345, 355, 234, 198, 400, 256, 323, 310]}


df = pd.DataFrame(d) #function must take a pandas dataframe


def Rank1 (dataframe, sortby,partitionby):
    sortdf = dataframe.sort(sortby, ascending=[1]) #Sort data into new dataframe
    sortdf['NextValue'] = sortdf.join(sortby).shift()


Rank1(df, ['City'], ['Weight'])
```

The last line in the function causes it to fail.  I basically need it to say:

```
sortdf['NextValue'] = sortdf['City'].shift()
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer and give an example of what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is the the last line as you say, why not just passing the column names as strings?:

```
#Some dummy data for testing
d = {'City': ['London', 'New York', 'New York', 'London', 'Paris',
                    'Paris', 'New York', 'New York', 'London', 'Paris'],
              'Weight': [225, 454, 345, 355, 234, 198, 400, 256, 323, 310]}

 df = pd.DataFrame(d) #function must take a pandas dataframe
 df = df.ix[:11]

 def Rank1 (dataframe, sortby,partitionby):
     sortdf = dataframe.sort(sortby, ascending=[1]) #Sort data into new dataframe
     sortdf['NextValue'] = sortdf[sortby].shift()
     return dataframe

Rank1(df, 'City', 'Weight')
```

Comment: All your function does is take a dataframe and return the same dataframe

Comment: Answer was really simple - cheers.  Also the function doesn't do much in this example because I'm just adding the code from the function that doesn't run.  I've not included the rest as it would add noise.